# Install Ubuntu to a 2nd drive

Tags: system-installation

So I decided to go for it and try and switch to Linux. Going to need to keep Windows around for a while until I know that all my personal / work stuff will work with Linux.

So I am trying to install it to a second drive. Downloaded Ubuntu, setup a USB installer. Boot from it, the options are:

1) Install alongside Windows (I assume this means on the same drive which I don't want to do)

2) Wipe Windows drive (Nope)

3) Something else.

I selected something else, choose the drive I wanted to install it on "/dev/sbd" and click install. I get this error:

> No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the
>   partitioning menu.

I tried clicking New Partition Table but that does nothing.

I'm stuck/lost. I tried looking up answers here already but they were either not applicable (talked about installing to the same drive as Windows) or over my head (I'm not familiar with installing Linux).

Comment: What's the story on the 2nd hard drive? Ever been used? Connected properly? What's on it?

Comment: @tlhIngan Brand new, nothing is on it. Installed correctly, showed up in Windows. Initialized as MBR. No partitions, not formatted or mounted in Windows.

Comment: Try creating a partition in Windows first. Might help.

Comment: In the installer's partitioning tool, make sure you've created a partition in /dev/sdb and that the partition's "mount point" or "path" is `/` (i.e. the root file system). That should fix your problem.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Yeah see these are the answers I've seen so far, things along this line. I can't find ay partitioning tool and don't know how to set the mount point.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Nevermind I looked around more and found out how to follow those instructions. Thank you for getting me down the right path.